# Increment value in update query mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, addition

I am trying to add two values in a mongoose function.

This the function im using:

```
Equipa.findOne({ '_id': req.params.equipaID }, function (error, equipa) {
  if (error) {
    return (error);
  }

  if (util.isNullOrUndefined(equipa)) {
    return res.status(204).end()
  }

  console.log(equipa.distanciaTotal + "------" + req.body.distanciaPercorrida),
  { total : {$add[equipa.distanciaTotal,req.body.distanciaPercorrida]}},
  console.log(total)  
});
```

The values in `equipa.distanciaTotal` and `req.body.distanciaPercorrida` are correct, and so is the `Equipa` found by `Equipa.findOne`.

I think it will be fine updating the document, but I simply cannot add the two values.

Comment: do you want to update document or aggregate the document?

Comment: I want to update the value **distanciaTotal** in a specific document (which i find correctly). The update consists of adding the current value of **distanciaTotal** to the value in **distanciaPercorrida**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) to increment the existing value

```
Equipa.findOneAndUpdate(
  { '_id': req.params.equipaID },
  { '$inc': {
    distanciaTotal: req.body.distanciaPercorrida }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could either use $inc

```
Equipa.findOneAndUpdate(
    { '_id': req.params.equipaID }, 
    { $inc: { distanciaTotal: req.body.distanciaPercorrida } }
);
```

Or save the document after updating it

```
Equipa.findOne({ '_id': req.params.equipaID }, (err, equipa) => {
    equipa.distanciaTotal += req.body.distanciaPercorrida;
    equipa.save();
});
```