# Update Field in MongoDB but need to consider old value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to Update a field by reading the old value from the document then update a new value to that field in MongoDB.

---

suppose in a document i have a field named Qty and it already has a value like Qty = 2;
now i need to update the Qty = 5;
So after update i need the Qty be 2 + 5 = 7;
no directly replace 2 with 5.
please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increment value in update query mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172755/increment-value-in-update-query-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a model like below.

```
    db.products.insertOne(
       {
         _id: 1,
         sku: "foo",
         quantity: 2,
        
       }
    )
```

The following updateOne() operation uses the $inc operator to:

- increase the quantity  field by 2

```
    db.products.updateOne(
       { sku: "foo" },
       { $inc: { quantity: 2 } }
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. i am using Linq (C#) and got it worked using the inc operator.